# Separate Settings.bundle for different iOS versions

Tags: ios, xcode, version, settings, bundle

After updating to iOS 8 the app has Notifications privacy settings, but for previous versions (iOS 7) I added such an option manually in Settings.bundle. Now it is useless because of the built-in settings but I would like to keep it for previous versions of iOS.

I only managed to duplicate my target for this reason, so now I have two targets and each of them has its Setting.bundle. It works like this, but this means I will have two different production builds which is not practical.

**Is there any possibility to add or filter out options in Settings.bundle based on the iOS version?** Because some options I still want to keep them for previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

No, since the same app will run on all the different iOS versions and every app can only contain one settings.bundle.